# Scraping PornHub Video redirects to Cornhub

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making my first steps in webscraping and wanted to get Video Data from Pornhub.

In a first step i went trough all the pages on the main page and collected the video links. This worked and i got a csv with around 100k links. If i copy/paste those links to the brower , those work fine. BUT, when i go over them with my script to get my desired values, it always redirects me to a Cornhub Video (i know this was an april fools day joke some time ago). So it seems that my request gets redirected, but i dont know how this happens and if i can do anything about it.

'''with open("links.csv", "r") as f:
lines = csv.reader(f)

```
for adress in lines:
   
    data = []
    print(data)
    headers = ({'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})


    sleep(randint(2,5))
   

    html = requests.get(adress[0], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, features="html.parser")

    print(soup)

   
    views = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json")

    json_data = json.loads(views.contents[0])

    interaction_stat = json_data["interactionStatistic"]
    views = int(interaction_stat[0]
                ["userInteractionCount"].replace(",", ""))

    duration = int(
        soup.find("meta", property="video:duration").get("content"))

    upload_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        json_data["uploadDate"][0:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    video_id = soup.find("form", id="shareToStream")
    video_id = video_id.find("input", id="attachment").get("value")

    data.append(video_id)
    data.append(upload_date)
    data.append(views)
    data.append(duration)

    with open("data.csv", "a", newline="") as f:  # Das hier über die schleife um es nur einmal zu machen
        writer = csv.writer(f) 
        writer.writerow(data)
```

'''

Comment: Mind sharing one of those URLs that get redirected?

Comment: i am not sure if i can post porn links on here.

But it is basically every link you take from the main page.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not within the standards of a website accessed daily by children learning to program. OP should understand this and remove it himself.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus yeah, iwasnt sure if i can post, so i checked before if there are pther questions regarding this site..and they are. so i fugred it is fine

Comment: Yes @OliverThomaschewski there are. T here are also questions pertaining to blackhatting, to doxxing, to stealing and distributing PII, all sort of things. What are we to do? Continuing flooding the website with such stuff, or demonstrate a little mindfullness, and (in your case) replace eventual adult references to something similar in structure but less damaging to kids, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are really old, but this works just fine. Maybe make sure you alternate your IP or take some time before the subsequent requests.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

lines = [
    "XX62f79e2ed1ed8",
    "XX63078405e84b6",
]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Host": "www.pornhub.com",
    "Refer": "https://www.pornhub.com/",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for line in lines:
        soup = (
            BeautifulSoup(s.get(line, headers=headers).text, features="html.parser")
            .find("script", type="application/ld+json")
        )
        json_data = (
            json
            .loads(soup.getText())
            ['interactionStatistic'][0]['userInteractionCount']
        )
        print(json_data)
```

For the videos I've used the output is:

```
3,339,324
384,482
```

Comment: I tried it with your code, but i get the same result...so it could have something to do with the ip adress...how would i be able to change it?

Comment: Well, why don't you use a VPN or a proxy?